# Reduce spacing between links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know this question has been asked a lot of time but, since I am new to HTML, I still need some guidance.

Based on the code below, how can I reduce the spacing in between the links in each column?

Code:

```css
a {
  color: white;
}

.footer-background {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #1c2a48;
}

.logo,
.nav {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav-pills {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="footer-background container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 center-block">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">

        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/opengovernment/prr/Pages/default.aspx">Public Records Request</a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/AgenciesAndServices/Pages/Default.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/ReportAComplaint/Pages/Default.aspx">Report a Complaint</a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/Terms/Pages/Default.aspx">Terms of Use</a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/Terms/Pages/Default.aspxx">Accessiblity Statement</a></li>

        <li><a href="https://lp.constantcontactpages.com/su/ErJFVZz/BrowardLife">Subscribe</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 center-block">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="https://b.granicus.com/ViewPublisher.php?view_id=15">Watch Meetings</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/Pages/Welcome.aspx">Copyrights 2022, Government</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="text-white" style="padding-top: 3rem; text-align: center;">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Seems pretty basic to reduce the padding on the links

Comment: will changing the padding help reduce the space in between the links in each column?

Comment: That depends on exactly what space you mean to reduce. If you're talking about the space between each list item's link, then yes. Inspecting the code shows they have a top/bottom padding of 10px and left/right of 15px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each column has a `padding` of `15px` left and right. You could reduce it e.g. to `8px` to reduce the spacing.

Here is the edit code, to see what i mean.

Hint: Maybe there is a css-utility-class for this within bootstrap.

```css
a {
  color: white;
}

.footer-background {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #1c2a48;
}

.logo,
.nav {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav-pills {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row>div {
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="footer-background container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 center-block">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">

        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/opengovernment/prr/Pages/default.aspx">Public Records Request</a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/AgenciesAndServices/Pages/Default.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/ReportAComplaint/Pages/Default.aspx">Report a Complaint</a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/Terms/Pages/Default.aspx">Terms of Use</a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/Terms/Pages/Default.aspxx">Accessiblity Statement</a></li>

        <li><a href="https://lp.constantcontactpages.com/su/ErJFVZz/BrowardLife">Subscribe</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 center-block">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="https://b.granicus.com/ViewPublisher.php?view_id=15">Watch Meetings</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.b.org/Pages/Welcome.aspx">Copyrights 2022, Government</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="text-white" style="padding-top: 3rem; text-align: center;">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

For the mentioned case in the comments, you need to change the `padding` of each `<a href="..." />`.

In the Dev Tools (e.g. the google chrome ones) you can the that there is already a selector (`.nav>li>a`) setting a padding of each `<a href="..." />`. So to overwrite the padding of this selector we need a higher [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). So i added `.external-link` to each `<a href="..." />` and added following selector.

```
.nav .external-link {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```css
a {
  color: white;
}

.footer-background {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #1c2a48;
}

.logo,
.nav {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav-pills {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav .external-link {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="footer-background container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 center-block">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">

        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/opengovernment/prr/Pages/default.aspx">Public Records Request</a></li>

        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/AgenciesAndServices/Pages/Default.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>

        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/ReportAComplaint/Pages/Default.aspx">Report a Complaint</a></li>

        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/Terms/Pages/Default.aspx">Terms of Use</a></li>

        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/Terms/Pages/Default.aspxx">Accessiblity Statement</a></li>

        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://lp.constantcontactpages.com/su/ErJFVZz/BrowardLife">Subscribe</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 center-block">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://b.granicus.com/ViewPublisher.php?view_id=15">Watch Meetings</a></li>
        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/Pages/Welcome.aspx">Copyrights 2022, Government</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="text-white" style="padding-top: 3rem; text-align: center;">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I meant changing the spacing in between the links in each column.

Comment: Ah i see. Then you need to change the padding of each <a href="" /> :)

Comment: Can you please show that in your code?

Comment: Sure give me a moment.

Answer (score 1):

if you using flexbox you can just use `gap`

```
.nav-pills {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line-height is set to "line-height: 1.42857143;", which can be reset to "1" for your nav-pills class. Otherwise the classes are being controlled by your imported "bootstrap.css" stylesheet.